# 2 columns with left design is not working properly in add to cart page?

Tags: magento

I want to use 2-colums with left design in add to cart page.I am adding this code in

```
app\design\frontend\default\casezilla\layout\catalog.xml. The code is

<reference name="left">
            <block type="catalog/navigation" name="catalog.leftnav" after="currency" template="catalog/navigation/left.phtml"/>
        </reference>
```

So the left column is coming at the bottom of the page not the left side of the page.I tried to solve this but unable to do that.
If anyone knows this,please help me out.
Thanks!
I found that in every 2-columns with left page the

```
 <div class="main">
    <ul class="page_coms-in"></div>
    <div class="col-main"></div>
    <div class="col-left sidebar"></div>
    </div>
```

under the main section `<div class="col-left sidebar">`is coming. BUT in add to cart page

```
 <div class="main">
    <div class="col-main"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-left sidebar"></div>
```

here

```
<div class="col-left sidebar"> is coming outside the main function.So anyone can tell me why it is coming outside the main thats why my left menu is coming at the bottom.If anyone have any idea to solve this issue then please help me out.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add that code in `checkout.xml`. Under `<checkout_cart_index>` possibly.

First set the template like this

```
<reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
```

after that add your `<reference name="left">` tag.

Comment: I have already added the above code in checkout.xml.After that i have added the <reference name="left"> in catalog.xml.
then also left menu in add to cart page is coming bottom of the page

Comment: why you are adding in catalog.xml..its for product page ..not for cart page

Comment: means you are telling that i will add also <reference name="left"> in checkout.xml?

Comment: in which page you want to show that ??...cart page or product page?

Comment: then you only need to add that in `checkout.xml` like i have written above..no need to add in `catalog.xml`

Comment: I added the code in checkout.xml, then alse left menu is coming bottom of the page.I have cleared the cache also. still also the problem is same

Comment: means the block is coming...and you are done with your xml...check the css part

Comment: By default left menu should come in left side but it is coming in bottom only in add to cart page.I tried to solve this, but i am unable to fix this issue.please help me out.

Comment: yes sure if the solution will help me then i will mark as accepted.
my site is in local now.........please see the problem above which i point out

Comment: you may have change your css..may be its not getting its desired width to show the left navigation..check the css part...xml is only used to add blocks or structures to phtml files..and if your left block is showing that means you have done with your xml..now look at your phtml file and css part for design purposes

Comment: there is only one 2columns-left.phtml page is calling for all.If in every page the design is ok except in add to cart page then i don't think that is there any problem in css. if it may be then also i am unable to find the solution.because if i am changing the css of add to cart page, then other page's design is not coming properly

Comment: these are basic html issue ..dont ask these here please..check your cart.phtml if you have done some modifications there...check why div is not getting closed properly..And be sure `NO ONE answer this type of silly issues`

Comment: thankew my problem is solved the problem is in cart.phtml page

Answer (score 0):

step1: Open checkout.xml file

step2: find ' < remove name="left" />' It may be at line no. 59.

step3: Comment or delete this line.